# Javascript string manipulation, combining numbers with strings

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get values from a data set. My function has to loop from 1 to 7
to get my opening hours for 7 days. what i need to do is:

Where openHours[i] the "i" stands for a number between 1 and 7. I would like to attach that number on the word "openHours" in order to create a new word ex. "openHours1"

What would be the best way to do that? The "alert(i);" is working fine and is generating numbers from 1 to 7. I just need to attach those numbers on the string.

So far i tried everything that can comes in my head but I don't use javascript often so i am kind of stuck.

Thanks for the help.

```
function hoursFunction()
{  
var i =0;
alert("Hello");
for(i=1;i<8;i++)
{
    alert(i);
    alert(hoursForm.openHours[i].value);
}

}
```

Comment: Do you mean string concatenation? Javascript is dynamic typed, so doing something like `alert('hello' + 1)` will give you 'hello1'.

Comment: What is the value of hoursForm.openHours?

Comment: @FlorianMargaine  yes that's what I meant. Sorry for the wording.
The value of openHours is a number the thing is the correct variable would be "openHours1" where the number 1 would get attached to the string somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: After your comment, it would appear you are trying to get the following variable:

```
alert(document.getElementById("openHours" + i).value);
```

However, I would strongly consider using jQuery (or another library) to handle this, and you could do the following:

```
$("#openHours" + i).val();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the bracket notation to access properties - they're the same thing as indices in JavaScript.

```
alert(hoursForm[openHours + i].value);
```